# Issues with rollup build process.argv

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, rollup

Receiving the following error when importing a component from my rollup package

```
caught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at ../REDACTED/dist/esm/index.js (index.js:22254:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/Routes.tsx (App.tsx:8:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/App.tsx (extends.js:15:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
.
```

The line with the error in the index file is:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbdsC.png)

I was able to use the 'rollup-plugin-replace' package to fix the issue with process.env, but I am still crashing due to the 'process.argv' section. No idea how to replace this, I tried a similar technique using the replace function but no dice. Any insight would be appreciated and please let me know if you need any more detail.